# Flurry Analytics from an iOS app - how to change the version number captured by Flurry

Tags: ios, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

- I have an iOS app that uses the official iOS Flurry SDK.
- I need it to report the 'version' in flurry as a custom string that I define.
- Currently, events in the app are reported as a version number, like 1.0.0, 1.0.6 (I'm not sure what this even represents, obviously it's not the iOS version):

[image]

- I need to report this as 'iphone' or 'ipad' based on which device is being used. I can detect whether the device is iphone or ipad, but how do I set the version number that gets sent to Flurry?

I can do this in the Flurry Android SDK by using FlurryAgent.SetVersionName, however there seems to be no equivalent in iOS. I've tried using the 'setAppVersion' method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS function for setting the version is `setAppVersion`. This needs to be called before the Flurry session begins. [Here](http://flurry.github.io/flurry-ios-sdk/interface_flurry.html#a4ccd9b24965b9f514f525a9eb15d071d) is the documentation.